# Parse for javascript - "error 209 invalid session token" when signing up a new user

Tags: parse-platform

I wrote a simple function in an angularJS application for signing up new users:

```
$scope.registerUser = function(username, password) {
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", username);
    user.set("email", username);
    user.set("password", password);

    user.signUp(null, {
      success: function(result) {

        console.log(result);
        $scope.registerUserSuccess = true;
        $scope.registerUserError = false;
        $scope.registerUserSuccessMessage = "You have successfully registered!";

        $scope.$apply();

        $timeout(function(){
            $state.go("user");
        }, 1000);

      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        $scope.registerUserError = true;
        $scope.registerUserSuccess = false;
        $scope.registerUserErrorMessage = "Error: [" + error.code + "] " + error.message;
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    });
```

Initially it worked fine, but when I deleted all the users directly through Parse.com, I can't sign up new users using this function anymore. Each time I get *error 209 invalid session token*. Here's a screenshot of my Parse database:

[image]

I've googled the error message and the solution is always to log out the current user. However, if no users exist this isn't an action I can possibly take.

So I would not only like to fix this problem, but also know how to prevent it in the future so my application can be used safely.

Edit: I created a user directly in Parse.com, wrote a function to log in that user, but got the same error. I am completely stuck until this session issue is resolved.

Comment: When there's the error force the app to log out. Something like this: `if(error.code == 209)logout();`

Comment: Please checkout https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#sessions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

delete all your session tokens, and anything else Parse related really, from local storage:

[image]

if needed turn off legacy session tokens, and follow [migration tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/session-migration-tutorial) from scratch:

[image]

Comment: It took me a minute to realize you were using Chrome Dev tools and clicking the Resources tab to reach the local storage information. Do you know how to do the same thing in Firefox? I did a quick search and apparently firebug doesn't have an equivalent resources tab.

Comment: As someone who is new to web dev, I've been frustrated on issue for 6 hours. Thank you so much.

Comment: It was helpful, i fell into same pit. ;)

Comment: Aldo great for testing in New incognito window.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same error when building apps with react native using back4app. to clear anything Parse related, from local storage:

add

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
```

in to the page and Use

```
AsyncStorage.clear();
```

See Example Below:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import Parse from "parse/react-native";

// Initialize Parse SDK
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"; // This is your Server URL
Parse.initialize(
  "APPLICATION_ID_HERE", // This is your Application ID
  "JAVASCRIPT_KEY_HERE" // This is your Javascript key
);
 .........


  _handleSignup = () => {

    // Pass the username, email and password to Signup function
    const user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", "username);
    user.set("email", "email");
    user.set("password", "password");

    user.signUp().then(user => {
         AsyncStorage.clear();
        if (condition) {
          Alert.alert(
            "Successful!",
            "Signin Successful! Log in to your account.",
             [
              {
                text: "Proceed",
                onPress: () => {
                  //in this example, i navigated back to my login screen
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
                }
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Alert.alert("" +error);
      });
  };
```